# Trying to make a calculator in C#. What is going wrong here?

Tags: c#, error-handling, calculator

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool run = true;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Make a choice or type 0 to exit: ");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Add 2 numbers\n2. Subtract 2 numbers\n3.Multiply 2 numbers\n4. Divide 2 numbers");
            int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (choice == 0)
            {
                run = false;
            }
            if(choice == 1)
            {
                int x, y;
                Console.Write("Enter 2 numbers to Operate on: ");
                x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
                y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
                Console.WriteLine("The Result is: {0}", Convert.ToInt32(add(x,y)));
            }

        }while(run);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static int add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x+y;
    }

    public static int sub(int x, int y)
    {
        return x - y;
    }

    public static int mult(int x, int y)
    {
        return x * y;
    }

    public static double div(int x, int y)
    {
        return (float)x / y;
    }
```

I'm fairly new to C#, so I apologize for the remedial question. 
Problem is that when I run and input 1, and enter 2 and 4, i get 82 back and then the menu is printed twice. This is clearly not correct. Can someone tell me why this is occurring? I assume it has something to do why my conversions, but I would like to know for sure why the language behaves like it does, because this seems like it should work. Thank you for the help.

Edit: I'm not sure why I got downvoted, please let me know what I did wrong...

Here is a sample output:

```
Make a choice or type 0 to exit:
1. Add 2 numbers
2. Subtract 2 numbers
3. Multiply 2 numbers
4. Divide 2 numbers
1
Enter 2 numbers to Operate on: 2 4
The Result is: 82
Make a choice or type 0 to exit:
1. Add 2 numbers
2. Subtract 2 numbers
3. Multiply 2 numbers
4. Divide 2 numbers
Make a choice or type 0 to exit:
1. Add 2 numbers
2. Subtract 2 numbers
3. Multiply 2 numbers
4. Divide 2 numbers
```

Comment: Please read the documentation for [`Console.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx). Does it do what you *expect* it to do? (Also, note that it already returns an `int`, as does `add`, so your conversions are completely pointless at present)

Comment: Damien, it says it is supposed to read the next character. If i input 2 ints, shouldn't it read them back to back like I wrote?

Comment: You appear to be entering 3 characters, `2`, a space, and `4` (followed by enter) - so you two reads read the `2` character and the space character. If you had entered `2`, `2`, a space, `4` and a `1`, followed by enter), that is the string `22 41`, your two reads would read the two `2` characters. So, is that what you *expect*?

Comment: Does C# recognize a space as a '2' and an enter as a '1'?

Comment: Console.Read() reads only the next character from standard input. I suggest you to use Console.ReadLine() and ask user to enter each number separately. Readline() reads the next line of characters from the standard input stream so you won't have this problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
```

You should not use `Read` here. `Read` reads in a single character and converts it to the corresponding ASCII value. Basically, you're adding to ASCII values together.

Solutions:

You just change it to `ReadLine`:

```
x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

But if you want the two numbers to be separated by a space, like `2 4`, you can do:

```
string[] numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
x = Convert.ToInt32(numbers[0]);
y = Convert.ToInt32(numbers[1]);
```

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it and it made sense. Thank you for not only answering, but also giving an explanation as to what I did wrong. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Use Int32.TryParse to avoid exceptions in case user enters non numeric input